# android.view.WindowLeaked(Progress dialog is leaking to new activity)

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have got this code in my Async task to go to a new activity when doInBackgound is completed, but no matter what I do, I always get the window leak error, I have also tried adding delay to the the progress bar, but with no success. Can anyone help me? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please always post your code as text, not as images, to ease the task of debugging and answering by other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your `Activity` is finished and the `ProgressDialog` is theoretically still "displaying" which is not possible (since the `Activity` where it is displayed is gone), hence this error occurs. To prevent it remove the `Handler` around the `dialog dismiss` then it should work :)